# TypeError: server.listen is not a function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, visual-studio-code

When i create new folder i can able to see server.listen method but i can't see this method in my another folder which i use for NODEJS codes. I use Visual Studio Code and I can't understand why.

```
const http = require('http');   

const server = http.createServer = ((req, res) => { 

    console.log(req);

});

server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`http.createServer` is a function which takes the handler function as an argument, so you call it like this:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
});
```

In the code you posted, `http.createServer = ((req, res) => {`... attempts to *assign* the function *to* `http.createServer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cbr ! It was tiny mistake that i made. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score -1):

Module `http` included in node. Try install `@types/node`. It works on me.

```js
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer(() => {
  console.log('got')
})

server.listen(3000)
```

Also, req and res should had type notation except any.